# Add background image error

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, uicolor

I have the following line of code:

```
scene?.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "background.png")!)
```

When I run this I don't see my background image. But I just see a black screen with all the other buttons and stuff I made but I don't see the background image.

Sorry to say your last suggestion also didn't work. but i found this piece of code:

```
let backgroundImage = UIImageView(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
backgroundImage.image = UIImage(named: "background.jpg")
self.view.insertSubview(backgroundImage, atIndex: 0)
```

This shows me my background image! but now i don't see my `SKSpriteNode` images anymore... maybe you have a suggestion on how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

The code you provide is OK. If the image is located correctly, the problem has to be the scene? variable.

Try this in your viewDidLoad function.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "background.png")!)
}
```

If this doesnt works try to link the image from the storyboard. Add UIImageView and set your background image for the Image property in the Attribute Inspector.

[image: Storyboard Image]

I have tried:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "Background")!)
```

With this in my Assets:

[image: Assets]

And I get this result:

[image]

I've found this into the apple documentation for the insert subview method

> Views can have only one superview. If view already has a superview and that view is not the receiver, this method removes the previous superview before making the receiver its new superview.

It maybe the reason why you can't see it.

Comment: the image is in the assets folder so i suppose that is ok. what variable do you mean by scene variable? what am i looking for? i am quite new to swift and programming in general

Comment: oke thanks for the answer but now i have a gray background instead of the back one... any suggestions

Comment: sorry still doesnt work.. see my updated post for the next question/ possible solution

Comment: and how would i do that?